# Magento 2.2.2 - Change Cart page design as per Luma Theme

Tags: magento2, cart, theme

My custom theme inherits from `Blank` and the cart page is seen as below

[image: blank-cart-page]

Tried below code and placed under `Vendor/Themename/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.container">
            <container name="cart.discount" label="Cart Discount Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="cart-discount" after="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="checkout.cart.crosssell" destination="checkout.cart.container" after="-" />
        <move element="checkout.cart.coupon" destination="cart.discount" />
        <move element="checkout.cart.shortcut.buttons" destination="checkout.cart.methods" after="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

How do I achieve below like `Luma` theme

1. Changing edit button to icon as per luma theme
2. Change remove item button to icon as per luma theme
3. Remove continue shopping button
4. Remove Clear shopping cart button

[image]